# Browser cache clearing for Angular updates?

Tags: angularjs, caching, browser-cache

I want to make sure my application is always using the most recently deployed files.  I've done this in the past, in other frameworks, with `fingerprinting` my assets and `js` files.  I can't seem to find a good solution to `fingerprint` Angular's assets and `AMD` files.

How do you clear browser cache or update an `Angular` app when it's cached in the browser?

Comment: Isnt it the server which tells you to cache js or not?

Comment: Yes, but `fingerprinting`, in my opinion, is a better solution than using `HTTP headers` in both simplicity and design.  Determining if an asset is no longer needed on the client side, like with `fingerprinting`, is better than waiting for an asset to expire, especially if one deploys often.

Comment: I use grunt-filerev during my release build which puts a short hash in the file name which forces the browser to download the asset

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem and this is how I solved it:

1. In index.html file I've added manifest:

   ```
   <html manifest="cache.manifest">
   ```
2. In `<head>` section included script updating the cache:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="update_cache.js"></script>
   ```
3. In `<body>` section I've inserted onload function:

   ```
   <body onload="checkForUpdate()">
   ```
4. In cache.manifest I've put all files I want to cache. It is important now that it works in my case (Apache) just by updating each time the "version" comment. It is also an option to name files with "?ver=001" or something at the end of name but it's not needed. Changing just # version 1.01 triggers cache update event.

   ```
   CACHE MANIFEST
   /# version 1.01 +(Remove the forward slash)
   style.css
   imgs/logo.png
   /# all other files (Remove the forward slash)
   ```

It's important to include 1., 2. and 3. points only in index.html. Otherwise

```
GET http://foo.bar/resource.ext net::ERR_FAILED
```

occurs because every "child" file tries to cache the page while the page is already cached.

5. In `update_cache.js` file I've put this code

   ```
   function checkForUpdate()
   {
        if (window.applicationCache != undefined 
               && window.applicationCache != null)
        {
            window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready'
                                                        , updateApplication);
        }
   }
   function updateApplication(event)
   {
        if (window.applicationCache.status != 4) return;
        window.applicationCache.removeEventListener('updateready'
                                                        , updateApplication);
        window.applicationCache.swapCache();
        window.location.reload();
    }
   ```

   Now you just change files and in manifest you have to update version comment. Now visiting index.html page will update the cache.

This will work for angular applications as well. It is working for my application.